# AWS Cognito: Generate token and after refresh it with amazon-cognito-identity-js SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

i'm implementing a node.js backend using the amazon-cognito-identity-js.

I want to create a login(username, password) and refreshToken(token) APIs.

This is my code:

```
import { AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUser, CognitoUserPool, CognitoRefreshToken } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js"


   
public loginWithAmazonCognitoIdentity (username: string, password: string){
        
        var authenticationData = {
        Username : username,
        Password : password,
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'eu-north-1_xxxxxx',
        ClientId : '3al0l3mhcxxxxxqgnp789987'
    };
    var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username : username,
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    const user = cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
            console.log("token: " + accessToken);
            var refresh = result.getRefreshToken().getToken();
            console.log("RefreshToken: " + refresh);
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        },

    });

}
```

This function returns an accessToken and a refreshToken without errors.

After this, i have implemented this function:

```
public refreshToken(refreshToken)
    var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'eu-north-1_xxxxxx',
            ClientId : '3al0l3mhcxxxxxqgnp789987'
            };
            var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    
            var userData = {
                Username : 'lacucudi',
                Pool : userPool
            };
            var cognitoUser  = new  CognitoUser(userData);
            var token = new CognitoRefreshToken({ RefreshToken: refreshToken })
            cognitoUser.refreshSession(token, (err, session) => { if (err) {console.log(err)} else console.log('session: ' + JSON.stringify(session)) });
}
```

but passing the refreshToken previously retrieved it returns an:

> NotAuthorizedException: Invalid Refresh Token.

Can anyone tell me what is the correct backend implementation of these 2 apis ?

Comment: Maybe Username, UserPoolId, ClientId or refreshToken is invalid. You use callback style, but I don't see the callback function parameters of your function (ex: `loginWithAmazonCognitoIdentity`), how do you can use the "result" outside of the function?

Comment: Username and  UserPoolId are same of login function above that returns an id token, access_token and refresh_token populated

Comment: Copy and paste your refresh token to https://jwt.io/ , the content of the token payload should appear.

Comment: @hoangdv error message was returned because device tracking option was enabled in Cognito settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
    import Amplify, { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
    import {
        AdminCreateUserCommand,
        AdminSetUserPasswordCommand,
        AuthFlowType,
        CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
        CognitoIdentityProviderClientConfig,
        GetUserCommand,
        InitiateAuthCommand,
        MessageActionType,
        RevokeTokenCommand,
    } from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";

    public async login(username: string, password: string): Promise<AuthTokens> {
            if (!username || !password) {
                throw new HttpException(400, "Please provide both username and password");
            }
    
            Amplify.configure({ Auth: config.auth });
    
            const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
    
            if (!user.signInUserSession) {
                throw new HttpException(500, `Could not authenticate user ${username}`);
            }
    
            const {
                signInUserSession: {
                    accessToken: { jwtToken: access_token },
                    idToken: { jwtToken: id_token },
                    refreshToken: { token: refresh_token },
                },
            } = user;
    
            return {
                id_token,
                access_token,
                refresh_token,
            };
        }


public async refresh(refresh_token: string): Promise<AuthTokens> {
        if (!refresh_token) {
            throw new HttpException(400, "Please provide a refresh token");
        }

        const refreshTokenAuth = new InitiateAuthCommand({
            ClientId: config.auth.userPoolWebClientId,
            AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH,
            AuthParameters: {
                REFRESH_TOKEN: refresh_token,
            },
        });
        const response = await this.client.send(refreshTokenAuth);

        const {
            AuthenticationResult: { AccessToken, IdToken },
        } = response;

        return {
            refresh_token,
            access_token: AccessToken,
            id_token: IdToken,
        };
    }


public async logout(refreshToken: string): Promise<boolean> {
        if (!refreshToken) {
            throw new HttpException(400, "Please provide a refresh token");
        }
        try {
            const command = new RevokeTokenCommand({
                ClientId: config.auth.userPoolWebClientId,
                Token: refreshToken,
            });
            const response = await this.client.send(command);
            const { httpStatusCode } = response.$metadata;
            return httpStatusCode == 200 ?? true;
        } catch (e) {
            logger.error(e);
            throw new HttpException(500, e);
        }
    }
```

I used **aws-amplify** for login and **aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider** for other operations.

> **NotAuthorizedException: Invalid Refresh Token**

error message was returned because the device tracking option was enabled in Cognito settings.

It' s incredible for a service provided by AWS to give wrong error messages and very little documentation about it